# Unable to get value of the property 'split': object is null or undefined

Tags: object, null, split, undefined

Newbie to HTML here. Using IE9, I'm getting the Error on Page Unable to get value of the property 'split': object is null or undefined. The selected code section is

```
var     retDate = null
var     oscriptDateString = form._1_1_56_1.value
if ( oscriptDateString != '?' )
{
var     temp = oscriptDateString.split( '/' )
var     temp2 = temp[ 3 ].split( ':' )  //Getting Error Here
var     yearX = parseInt( temp[ 1 ] )
var     monthX = parseInt( temp[ 2 ] ) - 1
var     dayX = parseInt( temp2[ 0 ] )
var     hourX = parseInt( temp2[ 1 ] )
var     minuteX = parseInt( temp2[ 2 ] )
var     secondX = parseInt( temp2[ 3 ] )
retDate = new Date( yearX, monthX, dayX, hourX, minuteX, secondX )
}
return retDate
```

It only returns this error when the field is blank. Otherwise works fine. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You are reading from a field called _1_1_56_1

```
var     oscriptDateString = form._1_1_56_1.value
```

You then split this field, and name the result `temp`

```
var     temp = oscriptDateString.split( '/' )
```

If your `temp` is empty/null/undefined, because the above assignment failed (because the field was empty or it contained no slash...

```
temp[ 3 ].split( ':' )
```

Then `temp` here will be undefined. You can't call the fourth element (third position) of nothing.